# Remove portion a list by conditions?

Tags: python, string, list

Current I have fixed tool to extract list of string from executable file, which I do not have direct access to this tool's source code to alter it's behaviours.

This tool will also extract lot's of XML, HTML tags contents from executable file, which is consider noise for my current ML algorithm.

I want to remove those XML, HTML tag contents from the list, but remain others strings,
for example, I have following list of strings:

```py
["S'&W ",
 'GetModuleHandleA',
  ......
 'CoInitialize',
 'SHELL32.DLL',
 'ShellExecuteExA',
 'SHLWAPI.DLL',
 'PathQuoteSpacesA',
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>',
 '<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">',
 '  <assemblyIdentity',
 '    version="1.0.0.0"',
 '    processorArchitecture="X86"',
 '    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApp"',
 '    type="win32" />',
 '  <description></description>',
 '  <dependency>',
 '    <dependentAssembly>',
 '      <assemblyIdentity',
 '        type="win32"',
 '        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"',
 '        version="6.0.0.0"',
 '        processorArchitecture="X86"',
 '        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"',
 '        language="*" />',
 '    </dependentAssembly>',
 '  </dependency>',
 '</assembly>',
 '']
```

I want to remove those strings belongs to XML tag:

```py
['<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>',
 '<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">',
 '  <assemblyIdentity',
 '    version="1.0.0.0"',
 '    processorArchitecture="X86"',
 '    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApp"',
 '    type="win32" />',
 '  <description></description>',
 '  <dependency>',
 '    <dependentAssembly>',
 '      <assemblyIdentity',
 '        type="win32"',
 '        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"',
 '        version="6.0.0.0"',
 '        processorArchitecture="X86"',
 '        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"',
 '        language="*" />',
 '    </dependentAssembly>',
 '  </dependency>',
 '</assembly>',
]
```

but keep other strings in the list.

Looking for some suggestion to get this done.

Comment: it seems you need to copy from this list to new list until you get line with `<?xml`

Comment: For those lines with `<` and `</`, and `/>` can easily removed, but those in between of them, such as `type="win32"',`, `name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"'` I have no idea how to filter them out without deleting other string that are not in this tag cluster

Comment: it seems you don't have to check every line but you can skip all lines after at line `<?xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example data it seems you have to keep all until line with `<?xml>`

So you can get line by line and put in new list until you

```
new_data = []

for line in data:
    if line.startswith('<?xml'):
        break
    new_data.append(line)
```

---

If you have more complex data then you may need check other words and skip them. You may also check it after removing spaces. But this need long list of words (I show only for 3 items)

```
for line in data:
    if not line.strip().startswith( ('<', 'version=', 'processorArchitecture=' ) ):
       new_data.append(line)
```

Or you may check if line starts with `<` or ends with `>` or has `=` inside

```
new_data = []

for line in data:
    temp = line.strip()
    if not temp.startswith('<') and not temp.endswith('>') and ('=' not in temp):
        new_data.append(line)
```

---

```
data = ["S'&W ",
 'GetModuleHandleA',

 'CoInitialize',
 'SHELL32.DLL',
 'ShellExecuteExA',
 'SHLWAPI.DLL',
 'PathQuoteSpacesA',
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>',
 '<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">',
 '  <assemblyIdentity',
 '    version="1.0.0.0"',
 '    processorArchitecture="X86"',
 '    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApp"',
 '    type="win32" />',
 '  <description></description>',
 '  <dependency>',
 '    <dependentAssembly>',
 '      <assemblyIdentity',
 '        type="win32"',
 '        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"',
 '        version="6.0.0.0"',
 '        processorArchitecture="X86"',
 '        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"',
 '        language="*" />',
 '    </dependentAssembly>',
 '  </dependency>',
 '</assembly>',
 '']

print('--- version 1 ---')

new_data = []

for line in data:
    if line.startswith('<?xml'):
        break
    new_data.append(line)

for line in new_data:
    print(line)

print('--- version 2 ---')

new_data = []

for line in data:
    temp = line.strip()
    if not temp.startswith('<') and not temp.endswith('>') and ('=' not in temp):
        new_data.append(line)

for line in new_data:
    print(line)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another method is to use variable i.e. `keep = True` to control which part of list to keep and which part to skip. You keep lines only when `keep` is `True`

At start you set `keep = True`. When you find `<?xml` then you set `keep = False`. And when you find closing `'</assembly>'>` then you set again `keep = True`. If you have always `xml` with indentation then you could even check if line starts with `</` to get last line  of `xml`

```
data = [
 "S'&W ",
 'GetModuleHandleA',
 'CoInitialize',
 'SHELL32.DLL',
 'ShellExecuteExA',
 'SHLWAPI.DLL',
 'PathQuoteSpacesA',
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>',
 '<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">',
 '  <assemblyIdentity',
 '    version="1.0.0.0"',
 '    processorArchitecture="X86"',
 '    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApp"',
 '    type="win32" />',
 '  <description></description>',
 '  <dependency>',
 '    <dependentAssembly>',
 '      <assemblyIdentity',
 '        type="win32"',
 '        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"',
 '        version="6.0.0.0"',
 '        processorArchitecture="X86"',
 '        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"',
 '        language="*" />',
 '    </dependentAssembly>',
 '  </dependency>',
 '</assembly>',
 'VARIABLE-AFTER-XML-1',
 'VARIABLE-AFTER-XML-2',
 'VARIABLE-AFTER-XML-3',
]

print('--- version 3 ---')

new_data = []
keep = True

for line in data:
    if line.startswith('<?xml'):
        keep = False

    if keep:
        new_data.append(line)

    #if line == '</assembly>':
    if line.startswith('</'):
        keep = True
        
for line in new_data:
    print(line)
```